# distribution signing ios app

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, distribution, code-signing

What i have wrong? The certificate and key are new generated from xcode Organizer. Looks valid.

I get error message:

error: Codesign check fails : /var/folders/zj/dx92zg8j0ds8sb_z2p7q1t7c0000gn/T/jQeOcYAITo/Payload/Direct Check-In.app: valid on disk
/var/folders/zj/dx92zg8j0ds8sb_z2p7q1t7c0000gn/T/jQeOcYAITo/Payload/Direct Check-In.app: does not satisfy its designated Requirement
/var/folders/zj/dx92zg8j0ds8sb_z2p7q1t7c0000gn/T/jQeOcYAITo/Payload/Direct Check-In.app: explicit requirement satisfied

where can be the problem, how could i fix it.

thanks

Comment: So I found the problem. It was wrong setted certification for Release. I though that the Distribution certificate is used for archiving. But it depends on build scheme and there i have Release in Archive tab. I setted the distribution certificate in Release and it work correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem. It was wrong setted certification for Release. I though that the Distribution certificate is used for archiving. But it depends on build scheme and there i have Release in Archive tab. I setted the distribution certificate in Release and it work correct.